# Rails, Restful Authentication & RSpec - How to test new models that require authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, restful-authentication

I've created a learning application using [Bort](http://jimneath.org/2008/09/09/bort-base-rails-application/), which is a base app that includes Restful Authentication and RSpec.  I've got it up and running and added a new object that requires users to be logged in before they can do anything(`before_filter :login_required` in the controller).  [edit: I should also mention that the user `has_many` of the new class and only the user should be able to see it.]

I've created the new model/controller using Rspec's generators which have created a number of default tests.  They all pass if there is no `before_filter` but several fail, as should be expected, once the `before_filter` is in place.

How do I get the generated tests to run as if there is/is not a logged in user?  Do I need a whole batch of matching not logged in - redirect tests?  I assume it is some sort of mocking or fixture technique but I am new to RSpec and a bit adrift.  Good RSpec tutorial links would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have a very similar setup, and below is the code I'm currently using to test this stuff. In each of the `describe`s I put in:

```
it_should_behave_like "login-required object"
def attempt_access; do_post; end
```

If all you need is a login, or

```
it_should_behave_like "ownership-required object"
def login_as_object_owner; login_as @product.user; end
def attempt_access; do_put; end
def successful_ownership_access
  response.should redirect_to(product_url(@product))
end
```

If you need ownership. Obviously, the helper methods change (very little) with each turn, but this does most of the work for you. This is in my spec_helper.rb

```
shared_examples_for "login-required object" do
  it "should not be able to access this without logging in" do
    attempt_access

    response.should_not be_success
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to(login_url) }
      format.xml { response.status_code.should == 401 }
    end
  end
end

shared_examples_for "ownership-required object" do
  it_should_behave_like "login-required object"

  it "should not be able to access this without owning it" do
    attempt_access

    response.should_not be_success
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { response.should be_redirect }
      format.xml { response.status_code.should == 401 }
    end
  end

  it "should be able to access this if you own it" do
    login_as_object_owner
    attempt_access

    if respond_to?(:successful_ownership_access)
      successful_ownership_access
    else
      response.should be_success
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 7):

When not testing the authentication but testing the controllers that needs the user to be authenticated I usually stub the filter method:

```
before(:each) do
  controller.stub!(:authenticate).and_return(true)
end
```

The above example works where my before_filter is set to the authenticate method:

```
before_filter :authenticate
```

and the authenticate in my app uses HTTP Basic Authentication, but it really can be any other authentication mechanism.

```
private
def authenticate
  authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |user,password|
    user == USER_NAME && password == PASSWORD
  end
end
```

I think it's a pretty straightforward way to test.

Answer (score 4):

I found a few answers to my own question.  Basically, I needed to understand how to mock out the user from `restful_authentication` so that the autogenerated rspec controller tests could pass even though I had added `before_filter: login_required`.

Here are a few of my just found resources:

[RSpec: It Should Behave Like](http://www.robbyonrails.com/articles/2008/08/19/rspec-it-should-behave-like)

[rspec, restful_authentication, and login_required](http://matthewkwilliams.com/index.php/2008/08/19/rspec-restful_authentication-and-login_required/)

[using restful_authentication current_user inside controller specs](http://rubyforge.org/pipermail/rspec-users/2007-August/002834.html)

[DRYing up your CRUD controller RSpecs](http://edspencer.net/2008/08/drying-up-your-crud-controller-rspecs.html)

Answer (score 1):

To mock a user being logged in, I hack into the controller to set `@current_user` manually:

```
module AuthHelper
  protected

  def login_as(model, id_or_attributes = {})
    attributes = id_or_attributes.is_a?(Fixnum) ? {:id => id} : id_or_attributes
    @current_user = stub_model(model, attributes)
    target = controller rescue template
    target.instance_variable_set '@current_user', @current_user

    if block_given?
      yield
      target.instance_variable_set '@current_user', nil
    end
    return @current_user
  end

  def login_as_user(id_or_attributes = {}, &block)
    login_as(User, id_or_attributes, &block)
  end
end
```